# For the Compactness Theorem for Propositional Logic, show that the extension is not unique.

Tags: logic

> During the proof of the compactness theorem, from an arbitrary finitely satisfiable set $\Sigma$ of WFFs, we construct a finitely satisfiable set $\Delta\supseteq \sigma$  such that for every WFF $\alpha$,  either $\alpha\in\Delta$ or $\lnot\alpha \in\Delta$.  Show that $\Delta$ need not be unique by describing an infinite, finitely satisable set $\Sigma$ of WFFs such that there is more than one possible extension $\Delta$.

Could someone please give me some guidance in answering this question? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If $\beta\notin \Sigma$ then $\Sigma\cup\{\beta\}$ and $\Sigma\cup\{\lnot\beta\}$ can be extended maximal finitely satisfiable set and they are not same.

Comment: @tetori: Not so fast. How about $\Sigma=\{\alpha, \alpha\to\beta\}$? Then $\Sigma\cup\{\neg\beta\}$ will not be satisfiable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, it is my mistake :(

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Suppose the language contains some unary predicate that is not mentioned in $\Sigma$ at all ...